# How to rotate svg circle in place?

Tags: html, css, animation, svg, css-animations

I'm trying to make this icon rotate like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y61pjmWLSn8

At the moment the icon is moving all over the place.
How can i make the icon rotate like the video?

```css
path {
  transform-origin: 50px 50px;
   animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-name: rotate;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}



@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    viewBox="0 0 1067.04 677.07">    
    <path class=""
        d="M164.41,202.61A52.49,52.49,0,0,0,149.93,201l-7.83-8.2L134.5,195l-8.29,2.39-1.58,10.92a52.37,52.37,0,0,0-11.4,9.07l-11.17-.56-4,7.23-.76,1.37-.75,1.36-4,7.23L99,243.14a52.38,52.38,0,0,0-1.63,14.47L89,264.77l2.39,8.28,2.19,7.61,11.12,2.26a52.31,52.31,0,0,0,9.07,11.39l-1.28,10.78,8,4.39,7.95,4.39,8.44-6.82a52,52,0,0,0,14.47,1.62l7.83,8.21,7.61-2.19L175,312.3l1.58-10.92A52.3,52.3,0,0,0,188,292.3l11.17.57,4-7.23.76-1.37.75-1.37,4-7.22-6.42-9.16a52.45,52.45,0,0,0,1.62-14.47l8.41-7.16-2.39-8.28L207.66,229l-11.12-2.26a52.12,52.12,0,0,0-9.08-11.4l1.28-10.77-8-4.39-7.95-4.39Zm21.12,69.74q-.37.69-.78,1.35c-.23.47-.47.93-.73,1.38a39.05,39.05,0,1,1-68.36-37.77q.38-.69.78-1.35c.23-.47.48-.93.73-1.39a39.05,39.05,0,0,1,68.36,37.78Z"
        />
  
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`transform-box: fill-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box) and `transform-origin:50% 50%` like so:

```css
svg {
  height: 100vh;
}

path {
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1067.04 677.07">    
    <path class=""
        d="M164.41,202.61A52.49,52.49,0,0,0,149.93,201l-7.83-8.2L134.5,195l-8.29,2.39-1.58,10.92a52.37,52.37,0,0,0-11.4,9.07l-11.17-.56-4,7.23-.76,1.37-.75,1.36-4,7.23L99,243.14a52.38,52.38,0,0,0-1.63,14.47L89,264.77l2.39,8.28,2.19,7.61,11.12,2.26a52.31,52.31,0,0,0,9.07,11.39l-1.28,10.78,8,4.39,7.95,4.39,8.44-6.82a52,52,0,0,0,14.47,1.62l7.83,8.21,7.61-2.19L175,312.3l1.58-10.92A52.3,52.3,0,0,0,188,292.3l11.17.57,4-7.23.76-1.37.75-1.37,4-7.22-6.42-9.16a52.45,52.45,0,0,0,1.62-14.47l8.41-7.16-2.39-8.28L207.66,229l-11.12-2.26a52.12,52.12,0,0,0-9.08-11.4l1.28-10.77-8-4.39-7.95-4.39Zm21.12,69.74q-.37.69-.78,1.35c-.23.47-.47.93-.73,1.38a39.05,39.05,0,1,1-68.36-37.77q.38-.69.78-1.35c.23-.47.48-.93.73-1.39a39.05,39.05,0,0,1,68.36,37.78Z"
        />
  
</svg>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use a small image with icon in the center you can animate the whole image.

```css
img {
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}



@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/i/materialiconssharp/settings/v17/24px.svg" width="24" height="24">
```

Answer (score -1):

Your svg box is too big. If you give it a border black, you'll see that the entire box is rotating, instead of the path. In order for this to work, you can reduce the size of the svg, to exactly fit the gear, which I've done for you.

Hope this helps

I've created a codepen for you https://codepen.io/OSquiddy/pen/QWvrrGe

**Edit:**

You can use `transform-box: fill-box`, as someone else suggested, but that doesn't solve the issue of your svg taking more place than you need it to. And if you try to reduce the dimensions of the `<svg>`, then your path inside will scale down as well.

To do as I did, ie. to make the svg fit your content perfectly, use a tool like [Figma](https://figma.com), which is like a free version of Adobe XD/Illustrator. Great for modifying and creating SVGs. Simply copy your `svg>` tag contents and paste it in there. Then select only the items you need, instead of the entire frame, right click and select 'Copy as SVG'. That will give you a perfectly snug SVG.